# How can I configure TDengine to use S3?

Tags: tdengine

Is there a way to configure TDengine to use Amazon S3 storage? I cannot find that in official documents? Is there someone know how to make TDengine to use S3 to store data?

Answer (score 0):

No, TDengine only support disk storage for now.